# When try to update CreatorUserId changing NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to update my table, when i update my entity `[CreatorUserId]` changing to null how can i stop that?

Using .Net Zero Repo

```
var projectAdmin = await _project.GetAsync(input.ProjectAdmin);
if (projectAdmin == null)
{
    throw new UserFriendlyException();
}
var projectRequest = await _project.UpdateAsync(new Project{Id = input.Id,ProjectName = input.ProjectName,});
var created = await _projectRepository.GetAsync(projectRequest);

return ObjectMapper.Map<ProjectDto>(created);
```

Comment: we will need more than just the code that isn't work help us with a little more than that very tiny fragment of source.

Comment: Like what u want?

Comment: Welcome to the community asking questions is one thing asking questions with good content to the question is another.   The more content to the question results in better answers to your problem(s)..  well the method that you are executing its signature, the startup.cs config. `CreatorUserId` is obviously in the contents somewhere but we haven't the faintest clue with your question content.  Secondly this is core right? Since you have tagged with non-core tags...

Comment: This is an FullAuditedEntity, the repository is from abp i have no controls! when i call update method the already inserted 'CreatorUserId ' it turning to null and 'LastModifierUserId' getting updated! hope this clear